# Blazor WASM authentication failing

Tags: blazor-webassembly, asp.net-authentication

I have a Blazor WASM application with authentication.  Been running it for months on end.  When developing it using Visual Studio it runs on port 7088.  There are two App Registrations in our Azure tenant (MyApp and MyApp-Client) and their authentication Tabs have the following URL:

> https://localhost:7088/signin-oidc

I also publish this application to another "production" server and that server's URLs is also here too.

The published application still works perfectly, but today (could have been anytime over the last week I guess as I've not run it locally) the authentication fails from my local machine.

The error in the browser is for a call to `https://localhost:7088/authentication/login-callback` which has a status of `(canceled)` in the browser developer tools.  The authentication window that pops up says "**localhost** refused to connect".

Not really sure on how to dig into this further....

Comment: For Azure AD authentication, the related configurations are: redirect Url in Authentication blade in Azure portal, client ID/client secret/tenant id/redirect Url in appsettings.json. You mentioned your code worked well for a long time so I trust the codes are correct. By the way, you mentioned `7078` and `7088` in your question description, is it the issue?

Comment: Hi @TinyWang - so, I think this is a visual studio issue...  If I start the application without debugging (either in debug or release mode) then it works perfectly fine.  But if I start it with debugging then it fails.  URLs etc are the same (using the Kestrel webserver)